# How can I edit my previous commit messages in Smartgit?

Tags: smartgit

I recently noticed that i have committed two tickets with wrong ticket numbers and I have to correct them now. I am new to smartgit and hence don't know much about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the last commit, you can use **Local|Edit Last Commit Message**, for slightly older commits, make sure you are using at least version 8 and invoke **Edit Commit Message** in the **Journal's** context menu. **Be careful when editing commit messages of already pushed commits.**

Answer (score 3):

In later versions of SmartGit version > 20.x  you need to enable a preference to do this.  The preference on the OS X version is at

Smartgit --> Preferences --> Commands --> Allow modifying pushing commits (e.g. forced push)